# Can a get request parameter's ciphertext have a number of bytes that is a non-integer multiple of 16 in AES-128?

Tags: encryption, aes, padding, httpresponse, padding-oracle-attack

I have been studying encryption/decryption and most recently the padding oracle attack. Now, in my studies, I have come across a URL that looked something like this:

http://(some url)?stuff=IfCmMrKNpduwAZW51Kz-HGcGROyJM8ul3Q3us3kzzQQe-rwWR1e7tv3pCWGkqKe7XCK5J9q0sUfv2V!Ot-7rlZ3meyeVtX44xib7oMV-Q6TpIfuD8FfHskAw9oY8cjM-5r2!bTwy-AhsnNTKTM9GClGQOCNIQhDZruztsRfsOR65BTgWm31ZepjLayhN-I8AjB6jkoZQBJZtXNk3VyJ3Cg~~

Now, I put that ciphertext in the stuff parameter into a character counter and discovered that this ciphertext consists of 216 characters (a.k.a 216 bytes). However, the number 216 is not a multiple of 16 (since 216 / 16 = 13.5).

AES-128 uses 16 byte blocks (and yes, the application confirmed that the data was encrypted using AES-128), so when the data was encrypted, it should have been padded so that the ciphertext would ultimately consist of a number of bytes that is a multiple of 16. That is correct, isn't it?

If that is the case, then why does the URL above return a 200 oK status and not a 500 internal server error for invalid padding? Why is it only when I delete a character in that ciphertext or change a character, that an invalid padding error is returned?  ( By the way, that url is not the real url. I didn't want to use the actual url, but that ciphertext is real). Am I missing something here?

Comment: If I understand correct, it's from Hacker 101 CTF challenge. This cyphertext is base64-encoded, that's why it's 216 bytes. After decoding it will be 160 bytes (it uses `~`, `!` and `-` instead of `=`, `/` and `+` to be URL-friendly).

Comment: In Base64 each character represents 6 bits, not 8.

Comment: Hey guys... I just studied up on base 64, and if every character represents 6 bits instead of 8 then this is still strange. 216 characters * 6 bits/char = 1296 bits. 1296 bits / 8 bits per byte = 162 bytes (not 160). 162 is still not a multiple of 16.

Comment: @Rikudou there are also padding characters. Anyway, you don't need those details to decode base64.